# Content of div is longer then div itself when width is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have `div` of fixed width containing only `input` text box and `width` of that `input` is set to `100%`. I expect it to fill the `div` but instead it is slightly longer.

Demonstration code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input class="content" id="Text1" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin solid red;
}
.content
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Result (Firefox):

[image]

This happens also in IE 8, Chrome, Safari... The overflow width seems to vary in different browsers.
How do I make the content to exactly fill the width of the `div`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) is a quick, easy way to fix it:

This [will work in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/box-sizing), and IE8+.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QkmSk/301/

```css
.content {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

<sub>[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding/5219611#5219611) for an icky IE7 compatible method.</sub>

Comment: so what is the cause of this strange behaviour ?

Comment: @drasto: The fact that you're applying `width: 100%` to an element that has a border and padding. `border-box` fixes this by including this border and padding *inside* the `width: 100%` calculation.

Comment: so I can set padding on `div` to 0 and remove the border(that is there only to show the problem - will not be needed in production html)  to fix it ?

Comment: @drasto: No. It's the border/padding on the `input` element. To see what I mean, take a look at this exaggerated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QkmSk/4/

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Don't forget to use content-box or padding-box if the above does not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need  to reset the paddings, margins and the borders. If you want to apply it sitewide, you can use a reset css like Eric Meyer's : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Or you can write your own. Just default it to your own values

Answer (score 0):

Also add a CSS reset to you page. the input may have some padding added!

Comment: `overflow: auto` won't help. In fact, it will just add ugly scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code, it shows fine here on Firefox. I suspect you have an issue with specifity: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Or, there is a problem with the surrounding html. I.e. unclosed tag.

Try putting that CSS and HTML into a plain file to see if it displays correctly. If it does, I suggest taking a look at the CSS properties of the parent elements.

If you don't have it already, download the Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox, then use CTRL + SHIFT + F to enable the clickable element property display. This will help you debug what is happening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's nothing to do with specificity or invalid HTML. See the unfixed version of my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/QkmSk/1/ - admittedly the effect isn't very clear in Firefox, but the red border is covered by the `input`.

Comment: That isn't the case here using Firefox 3.6.14. The code the OP provided worked perfectly here without any adjustment. The input box was inside the red border.

Comment: I was observing the issue in 4 major browsers as stated in question, the demonstration code was writen in blank page html and the `html` tag has no atributes so I cannot imagine any problem there. Try to increase resolution of your browser by pressing `ctrl+'+'`

Comment: hmm.. seems my browser had gone into quirks mode. *rolls eyes* :)