# <select> element is a bit shorter then rest

Tags: html, css

So I've set my input, textarea and select elemtnts width of 97%. Everything is showing fine, but select element is always a bit shorter then rest. See picture for screenshot.
[image]

How to fix this? :)

Okey I fixed it byt adding extra margin to select element, here is css.

```
#cat_add_form input[type="text"], #edtCatDescr, select, .fileUpload
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 97%;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    display: block;


    /* CSS 3 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

#cat_add_form select
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Make it 98% :) Can you show us some CSS?

Comment: can you post your html and css?

Comment: Just for the record, that's not CSS3. CSS3 would be this: `border-radius: 3px;` Those are browser specific tags which are not included in the CSS3 spec. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select {
    width:98%;
}
```

Just play with values until it looks alright,

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/tRmsY/)**

What browsers have you tested in?

Comment: Chrome and IE. I will do like you said since margin-right just puts the gap at the start. It's not pixel-perfect but at least it's better then 97%. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing).

This works in modern browsers, and IE8+.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tRmsY/2/) *([or 97% version](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tRmsY/3/))*, modified from @Myles Gray's demo.

[See here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219030/content-of-div-is-longer-then-div-itself-when-width-is-set-to-100/5219090#5219090)

[For a way that works in IE7, see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding/5219611#5219611)