# Div with margin-left and width:100% overflowing on the right side

Tags: css, html, margin

I have 2 nested div's that should be 100% wide. Unfortunately the inner div with the Textbox overflows and is actually larger than the outer div. It has a left margin and overflows by about the size of the margin.

How can I fix that?

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="margin-left:45px; width:100%;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

If I don't do the 100%, then the textbox is not 100% wide.

Comment: "about the size of the margin" - I'd bet on exactly the size of the margin :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just remove the width from both divs.

A `div` is a block level element and will use all available space (unless you start floating or positioning them) so the outer div will automatically be 100% wide and the inner div will use all remaining space after setting the left margin.

I have added an example with a `textarea` on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRJmW/).

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/qRJmW/1/) with an input.

Comment: If I remove the width then the textbox stays small, e.g. does not become 100%.

Comment: @Remy I´m not familiar with asp but if you are generating a `textarea` or an `input` you can just use css to set the width to 100%.

Comment: Actually this is what happens. But the div around it will not be 100% if I don't add the width part.

Comment: @Remy What does the generated html look like? By the way, I have added an example.

Comment: the asp.net control `<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="100%" />` will render something close to `<input type="text" id="[serverGeneratedFromID]" style="width:100%" />`

Comment: @mdmullinax Thanks, I was guessing either a textarea or an input, I´ll change the example.

Answer (score 7):

A div is a block element and by default 100% wide. You should just have to set the textarea width to 100%.

Answer (score 3):

If some other portion of your layout is influencing the `div` width you can set `width:auto` and the `div` (which is a block element) will fill the space

```
<div style="width:auto">
    <div style="margin-left:45px;width:auto">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

If that's still not working we may need to see more of your layout HTML/CSS

Comment: Actully, there was a float:left on the div from deep down in the CSS. Not sure why I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="margin-left:45px;">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The textbox will not fill the whole area if I do this.

Comment: Works fine in jsfiddle. Perhaps your asp attributes are wrong, try using css instead.

Comment: Had to get rid of a float:left on the div. Was hidden in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add some css either in the head or in a external document. asp:TextBox are rendered as input :

```
input {
     width:100%;
}
```

Your html should look like : http://jsfiddle.net/c5WXA/

Note this will affect all your textbox : if you don't want this, give the containing div a class and specify the css.

```
.divClass input {
     width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old post but this might benefit somebody who, like me, has come to this page from a google search and is at their wits end.

None of the other answers given here worked for me and I had already given up hope, but today I was searching for a solution to another similar problem with divs, which I found answered multiple times on SO. The accepted answer worked for my div, and I had the sudden notion to try it for my previous textbox issue - and it worked!
The solution:

add `box-sizing: border-box` to the style of the textbox.

To add this to all multi-line textboxes using CSS, add the following to your style sheet:

```
textarea
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks to thirtydot for the solution at

[width: 100%-padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding)

and

[Content of div is longer then div itself when width is set to 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219030/content-of-div-is-longer-then-div-itself-when-width-is-set-to-100/5219090#5219090)