# How to make an element width: 100% minus padding?

Tags: html, css, width, fluid-layout

I have an html input.

The input has `padding: 5px 10px;` I want it to be 100% of the parent div's width(which is fluid).

However using `width: 100%;` causes the input to be `100% + 20px` how can I get around this?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7FNgt/)

Comment: See this answer I posted not 15 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219030/content-of-div-is-longer-then-div-itself-when-width-is-set-to-100/5219090#5219090 This should work perfectly for you, unless you require it to work in IE7.

Comment: If you used my method, see the slight edit I just made on my answer. It ensures "even padding" in some browsers.

Comment: @Hailwood i have solution which keeping padding for `input` and supporting IE7

Comment: Please also see the answer below using the calc function

Answer (score 661, accepted):

[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) is a quick, easy way to fix it:

This [will work in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/box-sizing), and IE8+.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QkmSk/301/

```css
.content {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The browser prefixed versions (`-webkit-box-sizing`, etc.) are not needed in modern browsers.

Comment: I don't think this is that bad of a solution. In general, wrapping elements in an extra div is a good way to pad elements without pushing the overall width of the element beyond it's parent container.

Comment: Padding a wrapping div also produces non-identical results to adding padding to the input directly.

Comment: @thirtydot i have some more flexible and elegant solutions which keeps input's width

Comment: @thirtydot yeah, just leave it broken for IE7 and let M$ fix that :)

Comment: This also preserves auto resizing textareas for any of you jQuery people vs. box-sizing screws it up unless you apply that to the hidden div.

Comment: You could just use text-indent if all you want to change is the left padding of an input box. This will not change the width of the element.

Comment: It doesn't work when input has border... it is displaced by border width

Comment: See my answer below for a simpler and better solution or see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels

Comment: @FlashThunder You're right but that's covered by the inputContainer element. This element is used to define a border and the padding that you want for the input.

Comment: @thirtydot Could you explain why `display: block` is needed for the `input` element?

Comment: Please also see the answer below using the calc function

Comment: I don't understand this answer -- i've removed `    box-sizing: border-box;
`, clicked `Run`, and i'm getting the exact same results as before.  Using Mozilla SeaMonkey.

Comment: This was the first time I learned what `box-sizing` is for, great answer!

Comment: If you need this to work in IE7, you can read [an old revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5219611/2). And I feel really bad for you.

Comment: WOW! -- This was exactly what I needed. I couldn't figure out why my H2 I had set to `width:100%` was longer than its container. I already had border-box set on `body` tag, but this answer made me realize I needed to set `border-box` on all child elements also. Thank you so much!!

Comment: now this is real answer!

Answer (score 295):

This is why we have [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) in CSS.

I’ve edited your example, and now it works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/Bupr3/
All I added was this:

```css
input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Unfortunately older browsers such as IE7 do not support this. If you’re looking for a solution that works in old IEs, check out the other answers.

Comment: +1, but http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing IE 8? Also, https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill seems to provide a solution for IE 6-7.

Comment: +1, this is great if you don't care about IE (when using PhoneGap for instance)

Comment: What kind of wizardry is this? +1 for the answer and +1 for the comment above me (that's exactly what I need it for).

Comment: This should be the default behavior.. instead of +20 to width. Sometimes CSS seems seriously messed up.

Comment: To clarify box-sizing support on IE, for IE box-sizing property depends on IE Document Mode, it works on "IE8 Standards mode" & higher. So it will work in IE8 browser version also if document mode is "IE8 Standards mode". Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. box-sizing solves all problems related with padding-width/max-width relations.

Comment: @Soth unfortunately "default" in new CSS properties means "the way old browsers did it", right?

Answer (score 47):

Use padding in percentages too and remove from the width:

```
padding: 5%;
width: 90%;
```

Comment: Fyi, this solution is only ideal for non-flexible layouts.

Comment: +1, The problem with this would be the borders I guess. Normally, they only look "right" with 1 to 3 pixels max. The results are too unpredictable considering the the browser inconsistencies regarding sub-pixel rounding.

Answer (score 30):

Use css calc()

Super simple and awesome.

```css
input {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 15px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 15px);
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
}​
```

As seen here: [Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels) 
By webvitaly (https://stackoverflow.com/users/713523/webvitaly)
Original source: http://web-profile.com.ua/css/dev/css-width-100prc-minus-100px/

Just copied this over here, because I almost missed it in the other thread.

Comment: You need to manually program that in, though. Ideally it would be automatically determined.

Answer (score 29):

You can do it without using `box-sizing` and *not clear* solutions like `width~=99%`.

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/VSMmH/4/):
[image]

- Keep input's `padding` and `border`
- Add to input negative horizontal `margin` = `border-width` + `horizontal padding`
- Add to input's wrapper horizontal `padding` equal to `margin` from previous step

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="input_wrap">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    padding: 6px 10px; /* equal to negative input's margin for mimic normal `div` box-sizing */
}

input {
    width: 100%; /* force to expand to container's width */ 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 -10px; /* negative margin = border-width + horizontal padding */ 
}
```

Comment: That's a good trick, to use margin for input and padding for wrapper to compensate for the input padding.

Comment: Agree totally!!! I have used this solution and it works widely with no dirty tricks! This had to be the solution to every kind of these answers..

Comment: I don't quite understand what role the negative margin has - all I know is that if the value is wrong, then the box ends up to one side, but somehow a symmetric margin fixes this

Comment: Why not use box-sizing? it is there for the purpose.

Comment: @Ninthu, because box-sizing didnt work in all appropriate browsers back in '12

Answer (score 12):

Assuming i'm in a container with 15px padding, this is what i always use for the inner part:

```
width:auto;
right:15px;
left:15px;
```

That will stretch the inner part to whatever width it should be less the 15px either side.

Comment: Could you post a complete example of `width:auto` applied to an `input` field?

Comment: thats only half an answer. default position of elements is static, so left & right will do exactly nothing here. and width auto is also the initial value, so.. all this answer does is nothing :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is the recommendation from [codeontrack.com](http://codeontrack.com/problem-width-100-padding/), which has good solution examples:

> Instead of setting the width of the div to 100%, set it to auto, and be sure, that the `<div>` is set to display: block (default for `<div>`).

Comment: You shouldn't post link directly. You can include the information from that link. Reason being is, may be tomorrow that link won't be available and your answer will then no longer valid..

Comment: To clarify, and I think this is what Amnesh was trying to communicate, you CAN and should post a link your source(s), but it is even `more important to post a working code sample to demonstrate how to implement your suggestion`

Answer (score 7):

You can try some positioning tricks. You can put the input in a div with `position: relative` and a fixed height, then on the input have `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;`, and any padding you like.

### [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/wW4mY/2/)

Comment: What browsers did you test this in? :(

Comment: Hmm, works only in Chrome. But I know I got something very similar to work in FF & IE as well.

Comment: Seems like it's not working with `<input>` elements in Firefox (idk about IE). It works with `<div>`s, though. And no, `display: block` on the `<input>` doesn't work either :-/

Answer (score 5):

Move the input box' padding to a wrapper element.

```
<style>
div.outer{ background: red; padding: 10px; }
div.inner { border: 1px solid #888; padding: 5px 10px; background: white; }
input { width: 100%; border: none }
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
       <input/>
    </div>
</div>
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/L7wYD/1/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe browsers have changed since this question was last answered, but this is the only thing that has ever worked reliably for me to accomplish this:

```
    width: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
```

Then you can make the margins / padding anything you want and the element will not expand past its available width.

This is similar to @andology's answer from way back but if you make left/right both 0 then you can make `margin` and/or `padding` whatever you want. So this is always my default `div`.

Comment: Thank you. This solution helped me. I had a slightly different problem. Parent element had padding and I needed a fixed child element to be 100% but it kept being pushed over by the parent padding. `left: 0; right: 0;` seemed to be all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just understand the difference between width:auto; and width:100%;
Width:auto; will (AUTO)MATICALLY calculate the width in order to fit the exact given with of the wrapping div including the padding.
Width 100% expands the width and adds the padding.

Comment: Can you include an example where this works with <input>? Otherwise you're just sending people on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping it in a container. Container shoud have style like:

```
{
    width:100%;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, using `margin:15px;padding:10px 0 15px 23px;width:100%`, the result was this:

[image]

The solution for me was to use `width:auto` instead of `width:100%`. My new code was:

`margin:15px;padding:10px 0 15px 23px;width:auto`. Then the element aligned properly:

[image]

Answer (score -9):

You can do this:

```
width: auto;
padding: 20px;
```

Comment: This is not the same 100% - margin.