# Cross browser method to fit a child div to its parent's width

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, parent-child

I'm looking for a solution to fit a child `div` into it's parent's `width`.

Most solutions I've seen here **are not cross-browser compatible** (eg. `display: table-cell;` isn't supported in IE `<=8`).

[image: image showing intended result with a child div being the full size of it's parent, with inner padding]

Comment: If I get your right, just do not declare width on child.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The solution is to simply not declare `width: 100%`.

The default is `width: auto`, which for block-level elements (such as `div`), will take the "full space" available anyway (different to how `width: 100%` does it).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/U7PhY/2/

Just in case it's not already clear from my answer: just don't set a `width` on the child `div`.

You might instead [be interested in `box-sizing: border-box`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5219611/405015).

Comment: I think there is only one child?

Comment: Yup, I think you're right. The diagram confused me :( Luckily, I'd already written the "second part" of my answer, and that is the actual answer here.

Comment: you don't need to declare width attribute for child at all.

Comment: It's possible a style property that is part of a component you've included in your project is setting the `width` property and causing a problem.  In this case, explicitly set `width: auto` for the child div.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `box-sizing` css property, it's crossbrowser(ie8+, and all real browsers) and pretty good solution for such cases:

```
#childDiv{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%; //or any percentage width you want
   padding: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tk00pcz/)

Answer (score 3):

If you put `position:relative;` on the outer element, the inner element will place itself according to this one. Then a `width:auto;` on the inner element will be the same as the width of the outer.

Comment: Then just remove `width:100%;` and the box will fit in automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In your image you've putting the padding outside the child. This is not the case. Padding adds to the width of an element, so if you add padding and give it a width of 100% it will have a width of 100% + padding. In order to what you are wanting you just need to either add padding to the parent div, or add a margin to the inner div. Because divs are block-level elements they will automatically expand to the width of their parent.

Comment: i've uploaded a new image - sorry for the bad diagram ! of course i do know what padding means ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `width: 100%` in your child div:

http://jsfiddle.net/DanielDZC/w2mev/1/

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use that padding space... then here's something:

http://jsfiddle.net/qD4zd/

All the colors are background colors.