# Making the size of one div equal to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs, box and stylewidth. stylewidth is a child of box, which I've tried to make as large as stylewidth in a function. to that end I've added this line.

```
$("#box").width(("#styleWidth").width);
```

The problem is, box doesn't change in size, and I'm not sure why. is this the correct method?

Comment: have a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593425/best-method-to-fit-a-child-div-to-its-parents-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis on the inner width() function and the dollarsign, and make sure you wrap it in document.ready or add it after the elements are loaded in the DOM:

```
$("#box").width( $("#styleWidth").width() );
```

Comment: hold that thought, I forgot about the parenthesis as well, and now it works :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the jQuery dollar sign (before #styleWidth) and .width is a function, so it takes ().

```
$("#box").width($("#styleWidth").width());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't solve this problem with css?

You may be able to simply use `width:100%` assuming the positioning and document structure allow this.

Comment: normally I try to solve my problems without resorting to jquery, but in this case, I can't use a percentage width.