# How can I make the child div to have the same width as the parent div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a parent div that has the `max-width: 100%` (full screen width) and I want to make the child div to have the same width, but I don't know why it's not working. I tried child div `width: 100%` and `width: inherit` but still it has a margin. Is there a solution? The parent div contains a carousel above this child div.
What I want to remove is this margin:  [the margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs1Az.png)
For the child div I already used (you can see in the html below) bootstrap classes for margins, ms-0 and me-0;
The parent div looks good, the margins are fine, has no margin from the browser.

I tried all the solutions offered here
[Cross browser method to fit a child div to its parent's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593425/cross-browser-method-to-fit-a-child-div-to-its-parents-width)
but it's not working.

```css
.main {
  position         : relative;
  height           : auto;
  left             : 0px;
  right            : 0px;
  background-color : #eceaed;
  max-width        : 100%;
  }
.middle-box {
  position         : relative;
  height           : 250px;
  max-width        : 100%;
  border           : 1px solid black;
  background-color : rgba(96, 75, 254, 0.8);
  }
.middle-box::before {
  content          : "";
  background-image : url("../images/mountains2.jpg");
  background-size  : cover;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 0px;
  right            : 0px;
  bottom           : 0px;
  left             : 0px;
  opacity          : 0.3;
  }
```

```HTML
<div class="container main">
  <!--here is a div with a carousel-->

  <div class="container middle-box ms-0 me-0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution:

```css
.main {
    padding   : 0;
}
.middle-box {
    max-width : 100%;
}
.middle-box::before {
    max-width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yoo forget to set `.main` `padding` to zero... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css for `middle-box` uses `max-width`, which allows the content to expand up to a certain maximum, but will shrink the width to fit the content until that maximum is reached. You want `width: 100%;` like you tried before.

If `middle-box` still doesn't reach the edges of the parent `main` element, then use the `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` as needed.

I recommend using the element selector in Chrome dev tools. You can select or mouse-over the `.main` and `.middle-box` elements and Chrome dev tools will display the margin and padding for each element. Then you know where your issue is coming from. Other browsers have similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If by the margin you mean the space outside the parent div (`.container.main`), then that may be caused by the browser's default styling. Browsers add some default CSS, including a margin on the `body` element.

If not, you may need to add `padding: 0` to `.main`, or `margin: 0` to `.middle-box`.

I tried tidying up the code a little and put some comments here as well. I hope it helps!

```css
 body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  /* <div> is block-level, so it will span the width of its parent (body) */
  /* position: relative is not needed here; only on the child */
  /* left: 0 and right: 0 are redundant */
  background-color: #eceaed;
}

.middle-box {
  /* <div> is block-level, so it will span the width of its parent (.main) */
  /* position: relative is not needed here; only on the child */
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(96, 75, 254, 0.8);
}

.middle-box:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("../images/mountains2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  /* inset: 0 gives the same result as top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 */
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container main">
                <!--here is a div with a carousel-->
            
                <div class="container middle-box ms-0 me-0">    
                </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: The parent div is fine, has no margins, it looks good. The child div has bootstrap classes for margins ms-0 and me-0.