# How to prevent padded child element to overflow its parent?

Tags: html, css, width, padding

As you can see from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jWs8c/1/), the `input` seems to "overflow" its parent `div`. I'd like to add padding to the `input` without making it overflow its parent.

I would like to know the best solution/workaround for every browser (including IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc).

Comment: See the answer to this previous question: [width: 100%-padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding), but if you don't like it, you can use `box-sizing` CSS3 property like this:

```
input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jWs8c/9/)

Comment: Indeed the best solution, unfortunately is CSS3

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues Most modern browser already support this property, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: Uhm.. didn't know was so supported.  Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues No problem, you won't get any problem if your site is for IE8+, but if your visitors is from IE6/7, then you need a conditional comments for IE and then load other CSS for override that.

Answer (score 2):

Padding adds to the width of your object.  One option would be to remove the left/right padding from the input and just use text-indent, although this removes the right padding.

```
.inside{
    background: blue;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using hardcoded pixel-widths for your padding, you could use percentages, and subtract that value from the width:

```
.inside{
    padding: 3%;
    width: 94%;
}
```

Comment: The problem not want the text on input near the border. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Well , that one of the solutions I thought. Will see other responses , because I'm looking the best way and crossbrowser solution.

Other idea was using position: absolute; right:0; left:0 and define a width , then center using margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the width of the inside div as `100%`. A div will automatically fit the width of its parent container. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWs8c/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the try, but was .. but the example in stackoverflow was input.

Comment: Yeah I know I realized during my testing I just removed the `/2/` from the URL to get back to what I thought was your original code. But it wasn't. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input is inside the div but is located in the top left corner. Because the input takes-up 100% of the div's width it obscures the red background of the div. The div is longer so it sticks out the bottom making it seem like the input is on-top. Do the following:

- **Apply the padding to the CSS of the outside div not the input box**.
  You could apply a margin to the input if you want but I think padding
  the containing div is better.

  - Make the input box less wide than the div (<100%)

Comment: Then not fit perfectly center. Thanks for the help