# 100% width input with padding

Tags: css

How to make textarea/input that has left/right padding 10px and will be as wide as its parent.

```
textarea,input{
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    width:100%;
}
```

In that case input is wider.

Comment: A good discussion about solving this with box-sizing is available here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ (This is the solution Meliborn suggests, note what browsers it is compatible with. It's at the bottom of the article)

Answer (score 6):

```
    textarea{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:100%;
        padding: 10px
    }
```

Comment: @user1785870 For IE6/7 you can optionally use the **[box-sizing polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)** to provide `box-sizing` feature.

Comment: @user1785870 I have solution for IE7

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the good old [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). Padding is ADDED to the width, so in order to achieve the desired effect, you'd have to use percentages in padding also. Try this:

```
textarea, input {
   padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
   width: 96%;
}
```

Comment: im absolutely avare of this and box model. I know about it and it has to be pixel perfect.

Comment: Then as @Meliborn suggested, box sizing is your way to go (not sure if that works in IE7/IE8 though).

Comment: @user1785870 Another solution is to fix the size of the width (if it has to be pixel perfect).

Answer (score 1):

You can check my **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238699/1057730)** in related question

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/VSMmH/4/):
[image]

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="input_wrap">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    padding: 6px 10px; /* equal to negative input's margin for mimic normal `div` box-sizing */
}

input {
    width: 100%; /* force to expand to container's width */ 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 -10px; /* negative margin = border-width + horizontal padding */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin property to your css code.

Comment: This has to do with the box model adding padding to the width. So the width will be 100%+padding width. Please motivate why your solution will work.