# How to make table take up 100% of remaining space?

Tags: html, css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBKX/)

HTML

```
<div id="a">
    <table id="b">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#a {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#b {
    background-color:red;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want the table `#b` to span from 50px from the left of its container (`#a`) all the way to the right edge of of `#a`.

By setting the width to `100%` it goes off the page because it tries matching the width of `#a`. If I omit the width then the table is too small.

Setting the table to `display:block` and removing the width seems to give the [desired behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBKX/1/). Is this reliable, or is there another method of achieving the same thing? I'd prefer not to resort to absolute positioning.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding/5219611#5219611) suggests that `display:block` is reliable cross browser. You could also look at the 'box-sizing' property. I also really like this negative margin approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11238699/661447

Comment: You might also find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is is to [use box-sizing: border-box](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBKX/3/)

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
...
#a {
    ...
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Unlike Sirko's answer, this is will work in IE8+ and not IE9+

Another way is to [use conflicting absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBKX/4/)

Comment: Interesting. Why would border-box change the width? I know it changes the box-model so the width is calculated differently, but.. I'd expect to still collapse if it did previously.

Comment: @Mark The main change here is not the `border-box`, but applying `padding-left` to `#a` instead of `margin-left` to `#b`!

Comment: @Sirko: Oh! I didn't notice you had moved it. That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @Mark That's not my answer ,-) But it is just the "old" way of doing such a thing. Clear advantage is, of course, this is the better compatibility with older browsers, which do not understand `calc()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in CSS like this:

```
#b {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  /* your other stuff */
}
```

Most browsers support this nowadays. Have a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to see, which browsers don't.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBKX/2/)

Comment: Nice! Never knew about `calc()`.